# Uri.UnescapeDataString all properties on an object?

Tags: c#

I have some objects where some of the properties a URLEncoded.

What would be the fastest way to Uri.UnescapeDataString all properties on an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you're going to reach. Just assuming you want to automate the process of decode and do not want to call each one property separately and decode it.
The way to iterate through class properties is reflection. Actually, reflection never was fast. But it's also not clear, what you mean by 'fastest'.

Here is a short sample how to achieve it with reflection:

```
public class DecoderTests
{
    public String OneItem { get; set; }

    public String SecondItem { get; set; }

    public String ThirdClean { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ddd = Uri.EscapeUriString("Http://google tes.com");
        var decod = new DecoderTests
        {
            OneItem = ddd.ToString(),
            SecondItem = ddd.ToString(),
            ThirdClean = "clean"
        };

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DecoderTests).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var current = property.GetValue(decod) as String;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(current))
            {
                property.SetValue(decod, Uri.UnescapeDataString(current));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or just call each property separately and decode it. All the alternatives for Uri.UnescapeDataString like Regex.Unescape or HttpUtility.UrlDecode will perform much slower.

Comment: was just wanting to avoid doing this on 100+ object properties

Comment: So this sample with reflection will do it :)